# Arrays.toString returning odd result (Appear to be memory addresses)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create this two dimensional array in java and print the output, but when it outputs I am not getting the numbers or a two-dimensional structure. Java appears to be giving me what looks like memory addresses for each array result.

My code

```
public static int[][] generateSampleTable(int smallest, int largest, int sampleSize)
{
   int sampleTable[][] = new int[sampleSize][2];
   for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
   {
   sampleTable[i][0] = 5150;
   sampleTable[i][1] = 2738;
   }
   return sampleTable;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateSampleTable(1,1,10)));
}
```

My output appears like this:

`[[I@803816, [I@22b4b7, [I@1079ed1, [I@231c5d, [I@178cf47, [I@d65c13, [I@1fca60e, [I@1f99518, [I@fa7e97, [I@90925f]`

Ignore the `smallest` and `largest` arguments in that method as I haven't implemented the calculations for them yet and am not using them right now.

Other than what you see here, I guess I should tell you that yes, I imported `java.util.Arrays`

Not sure what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a dupe of that question.  the downvoted answers below are correct.

Comment: How is it not a dupe?

Comment: @jeroen because op isn't using a custom class.

Comment: And arrays are handled in the answer to that question as well. If you think it can use more information, edit the answer there to keep everything in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays.toString()` knows how to print 1 dimensional arrays. For 2-dimensional arrays you should use `Arrays.deepToString()`.